# bluetooth通信のMTU値は、Android機種に依存するか？

Tags: android, bluetooth

現在、Bluetooth機器とAndroidで通信を行う処理を実装中ですが、Bluetooth機器から受信するデータサイズが大きいため、MTU値の変更を行っています。(BluetoothGatt - requestMtu)

機種Aでは、MTU値の変更が問題なく実行でき、データの送受信ができているのですが、機種Bでは、MTU値の変更に失敗し、コネクションが切断されてしまいます。
(OnMtuChanged の status が 133)

機種に依存して、MTUの成功/失敗は変わるものなのでしょうか？
また、MTU値の上限等も変わるのでしょうか？

※補足情報
Bluetooth機器：Bluetooth 4.1

機種A:Nexus9
機種B:ZenPad10

Comment: iOSも含めた検証記事がありましたので、追記いたします。
http://qiita.com/hituziando/items/50c7ba7fb9f8917e1ebf

ただし、最後の結論部分にかかれているように、
「OSバージョンや端末によっては上限が異なる可能性はある」

という状況ですので、仕様等をご存じのかたがいましたら、ご回答、情報の補足等をお願いいたします。

Comment: 直接回答にはつながりませんしBluetoothはあまり詳しく無いのですが、4.1は省電力向けで3.0以前と比べると速度を犠牲にしてたと思うのですが、お使いの機器は3.0以前には対応していないのでしょうか。対応していればそっち(GATT以外)のほうが多分速度で出ると思うので。